Not able to serialize ZonedDateTime and PeriodDuration while converting a bean to XML
I used Joda-Time earlier. Now, I have migrated from DateTime(Joda-Time) to ZonedDateTime(java.time). I have also converted Period(Joda-Time) to PeriodDuration(Java). But as ZonedDateTime and PeriodDuration do not have any constructor, I got errors while serializing bean to XML.
I want to store the DateTime value in milliseconds (long) and the PeriodDuration value in a String in XML. Please suggest solution
Sample code for reference
https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/777

This question is similar to: How to serialize Java ZonedDateTime to XML file. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
